SAC calculated dimension that ranking another dimension based on measure values
I would like to create a calculated dimension in SAC Analytics Cloud, that ranks largest to smallest another dimension called country name based on another measure values. I want this to be dynamic, so it adapts when the measure values change.
Is possible to do it in the Calculation Editor?

